# Is there a way to compile Free Pascal code to a Symbian OS .sis

Tags: symbian, nokia, freepascal, fpc

We all know that Free Pascal can compile for the platforms that support Symbian OS, so is it possible to, painfully I must say, get a method to compile to the .sis format?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [port of Free Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/SymbianOS) to Symbian OS is not pretty ready yet. Though it is capable of writing helloworld applications, stdlib is not fully available yet.